# How to send value of taxtfield with data-remote attribute in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can handle php page but I m not getting understand what should I write with data-remote attribute to passing a value

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" data-remote="/path/to/remote/validator?<name>=<value>" id="emailField" placeholder="Enter email">
```

what should I write in place of

```
<name>=<value>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input element should have `name` attribute. The value of the `name` is the param in POST query.

Try to add **name="email"**

```
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control"
 data-remote="/path/to/remote/validator" id="emailField"
 placeholder="Enter email">
```

Remote Validator lib takes value of param `name`, current value of the input and creates a query.

Then in your PHP script you get this param from $_POST.

```
<?php 

$email = $_POST["email"];
```

Comment: I have name attribute so should I write data-remote="/path/to/remote/validator?name=email"

Comment: I have tried it but its not working...give me a link if u have any working example..

Comment: what component do you use? can'u provide link? Is it modal or validator?

Comment: its a validator. can u provide me any link where I can see the live demo and code but I want it in inline form...means I want to use it with the data-remote attribute not by JavaScript..I searched about it but I could not found any link.